# Is there a way to put a group element inside a rectangle to use for animations?

Tags: html, svg

Is there a way to place a group inside a rectangle object in svg and then treat that as basically a rectangle element. I want to do that because it would make animations much easier for me since I wouldn't need to move each individual element of the group but could just move the rectangle. I know I can use the translate property for the group to do animations but it would be easier if I could use fixed positions.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the elements in a group `<g>` in a `<defs>` and then refer to the `<g>` using a `<use>` element to display it. [A `<use>` element has x and y attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement).